# Security Risk on Window.postMessage in Node Modules Library

Tags: angular, npm, karma-jasmine

I am new in Angular 5 and front end stuffs.
I've been stuck on resolving an issue in terms of Vulnerability Attack.
I have a web application that uses a common component pack coded in angular 5.
(Shown on image below)

[image: WebApplication and Packed common component]

The problem is that, the packed common component which acts as a dependency in my Web Application have node modules that uses **"window.postMessage(message, " * " *)"*** which was found a security threat. We deploy the Web Application using ng build --prod which uses an AOT by default.

Some of the libraries that were found out with ***"window.postMessage"*** are:

```
node_modules/karma/context/karma.js
node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js
node_modules/setImmediate/setImmediate.js
node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/utils/iframe.js
```

I'd like to ask some help on:

1. Is there any way of deploying the common component library wherein the window.postMessage will not be scanned as a threat (I do not know if this is possible or not)
2. How can I solve the threat of window.postMessage when these codes are part of the different libraries we use? like karma.js

Hope someone can give me some light. Please help. :( Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve the issue above by updating our build script to:
ng build --target=production --environment=prod --base-href /contextroot/

Hope it would help the others who encountered the same issue! thanks